# Add pattern to nth line, if file has (n-x) lines [RHEL6]

Tags: linux, shell, sed

The following command will add pattern to the fourth line.

```
sed -i '4i pattern' file
```

But it is not working if I have less than four lines in the file. The requirement is I need to add the pattern in 4th line with empty prefix lines.

Expected Result: `cat -n file`

```
1  line1
2
3
4  pattern
```

GNU sed version 4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pad the file with a few blank lines to ensure there are at least 4 lines:

```
{ cat file; echo; echo; echo; } | sed -e '4i pattern'
```

---

If you want to subsequently trim the trailing blank lines, then you can pipe that into:

```
| sed -n 'H; ${g; s/^\n//; s/\n\+$//; p}'
```

or

```
| tac | awk '/./{p=1}p' | tac
```

---

Or adding only the minimum number of blank lines:

```
{ cat file; for ((i=$(wc -l <file); i<3; i++)); do echo; done; } | sed '3a pattern'
```

Note the sed program changed to append after line 3 instead of insert before line 4.

Comment: Thanks. It is possible to make echo dynamic. if we don't know the number of lines exist in the file. as title suggests

Answer (score 0):

Check if `file` has enough lines with `wc -l` (counting lines).

Display a warning if file has not enough lines.

```
[ $(cat file | wc -l) -ge 4 ] && sed -i '4s pattern' file || echo "not enough lines"
```

Comment: Be careful with the `A && B || C` pattern: if B exits with non-zero, C will be executed.

Comment: @Michael D want to add the pattern in 4th line even it has less the 4 lines. If previous line is blank also not a problem.

Comment: @glennjackman please check my edit in question.